# Prevent Content From Extending Outside of Div (and make it scroll)

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I have some basic markup (using Bootstrap 4):

```
<div class="card shadow m-3" style="width:500px; height: 280px">
  <div class="card-body">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-3 mb-2">
            <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/e/ec/Terrier_mixed-breed_dog.jpg/1024px-Terrier_mixed-breed_dog.jpg" class="img-thumbnail">
          </div>
          <div class="col-3 mb-2">
            <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/e/ec/Terrier_mixed-breed_dog.jpg/1024px-Terrier_mixed-breed_dog.jpg" class="img-thumbnail">
          </div>
          <div class="col-3 mb-2">
            <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/e/ec/Terrier_mixed-breed_dog.jpg/1024px-Terrier_mixed-breed_dog.jpg" class="img-thumbnail">
          </div>
          <div class="col-3 mb-2">
            <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/e/ec/Terrier_mixed-breed_dog.jpg/1024px-Terrier_mixed-breed_dog.jpg" class="img-thumbnail">
          </div>
          <div class="col-3 mb-2">
            <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/e/ec/Terrier_mixed-breed_dog.jpg/1024px-Terrier_mixed-breed_dog.jpg" class="img-thumbnail">
          </div>
          <div class="col-3 mb-2">
            <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/e/ec/Terrier_mixed-breed_dog.jpg/1024px-Terrier_mixed-breed_dog.jpg" class="img-thumbnail">
          </div>
          <div class="col-3 mb-2">
            <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/e/ec/Terrier_mixed-breed_dog.jpg/1024px-Terrier_mixed-breed_dog.jpg" class="img-thumbnail">
          </div>
          <div class="col-3 mb-2">
            <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/e/ec/Terrier_mixed-breed_dog.jpg/1024px-Terrier_mixed-breed_dog.jpg" class="img-thumbnail">
          </div>
          <div class="col-3 mb-2">
            <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/e/ec/Terrier_mixed-breed_dog.jpg/1024px-Terrier_mixed-breed_dog.jpg" class="img-thumbnail">
          </div>
          <div class="col-3 mb-2">
            <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/e/ec/Terrier_mixed-breed_dog.jpg/1024px-Terrier_mixed-breed_dog.jpg" class="img-thumbnail">
          </div>
          <div class="col-3 mb-2">
            <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/e/ec/Terrier_mixed-breed_dog.jpg/1024px-Terrier_mixed-breed_dog.jpg" class="img-thumbnail">
          </div>
        </div>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary w-100 btn-lg mb-3">Insert</button>
      </div>
</div>
```

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/ChiliTomatoNoodle/pen/qBNLxqq?editors=1000)

What I want is well, first of all for the content to not extend beyond the card :) After that, I'd like the `div` containing the images (`div.row`) to take up the remaining space after the space for the button has been allocated, and for any overflowing content to scroll vertically in that `div` (i.e., I need the button to stay fixed at the bottom of the card while the content in the `div` above is scrolled).

Solution with Bootstrap classes preferred, but custom CSS also fine. I don't want to have to manually specify the height of the `div.row`, would like it to automatically fill remaining space in the `div.card-body` (some flexbox magic?).

Thank you for your help!

PS

I have been able to constrain the content to the card by using overflow-auto, but only if I use it on the entire card body, in which case the button will scroll with the image content (not what I want).

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/ChiliTomatoNoodle/pen/yLJGvqy)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can implement a scenario like this.

[image]

```
.overflow-auto
```

**Preview the example**

```html
<!-- CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-TX8t27EcRE3e/ihU7zmQxVncDAy5uIKz4rEkgIXeMed4M0jlfIDPvg6uqKI2xXr2" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- jQuery and JS bundle w/ Popper.js -->
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ho+j7jyWK8fNQe+A12Hb8AhRq26LrZ/JpcUGGOn+Y7RsweNrtN/tE3MoK7ZeZDyx" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="card shadow m-3" style="width:500px; height: 280px">
  <div class="card-body overflow-auto">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-3 mb-2">
        <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/e/ec/Terrier_mixed-breed_dog.jpg/1024px-Terrier_mixed-breed_dog.jpg" class="img-thumbnail">
      </div>
      <div class="col-3 mb-2">
        <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/e/ec/Terrier_mixed-breed_dog.jpg/1024px-Terrier_mixed-breed_dog.jpg" class="img-thumbnail">
      </div>
      <div class="col-3 mb-2">
        <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/e/ec/Terrier_mixed-breed_dog.jpg/1024px-Terrier_mixed-breed_dog.jpg" class="img-thumbnail">
      </div>
      <div class="col-3 mb-2">
        <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/e/ec/Terrier_mixed-breed_dog.jpg/1024px-Terrier_mixed-breed_dog.jpg" class="img-thumbnail">
      </div>
      <div class="col-3 mb-2">
        <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/e/ec/Terrier_mixed-breed_dog.jpg/1024px-Terrier_mixed-breed_dog.jpg" class="img-thumbnail">
      </div>
      <div class="col-3 mb-2">
        <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/e/ec/Terrier_mixed-breed_dog.jpg/1024px-Terrier_mixed-breed_dog.jpg" class="img-thumbnail">
      </div>
      <div class="col-3 mb-2">
        <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/e/ec/Terrier_mixed-breed_dog.jpg/1024px-Terrier_mixed-breed_dog.jpg" class="img-thumbnail">
      </div>
      <div class="col-3 mb-2">
        <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/e/ec/Terrier_mixed-breed_dog.jpg/1024px-Terrier_mixed-breed_dog.jpg" class="img-thumbnail">
      </div>
      <div class="col-3 mb-2">
        <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/e/ec/Terrier_mixed-breed_dog.jpg/1024px-Terrier_mixed-breed_dog.jpg" class="img-thumbnail">
      </div>
      <div class="col-3 mb-2">
        <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/e/ec/Terrier_mixed-breed_dog.jpg/1024px-Terrier_mixed-breed_dog.jpg" class="img-thumbnail">
      </div>
      <div class="col-3 mb-2">
        <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/e/ec/Terrier_mixed-breed_dog.jpg/1024px-Terrier_mixed-breed_dog.jpg" class="img-thumbnail">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="card-footer">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary w-100 btn-lg">Insert</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

**For your second question:**

If that's what you mean, yes there is a way: For this, we use the (flex) structure.

```html
<!-- CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-TX8t27EcRE3e/ihU7zmQxVncDAy5uIKz4rEkgIXeMed4M0jlfIDPvg6uqKI2xXr2" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- jQuery and JS bundle w/ Popper.js -->
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ho+j7jyWK8fNQe+A12Hb8AhRq26LrZ/JpcUGGOn+Y7RsweNrtN/tE3MoK7ZeZDyx" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="card shadow m-3" style="width:500px; height: 280px">
  <div class="card-body h-100 d-flex flex-column">
    <div class="row overflow-auto">
      <div class="col-3 mb-2">
        <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/e/ec/Terrier_mixed-breed_dog.jpg/1024px-Terrier_mixed-breed_dog.jpg" class="img-thumbnail">
      </div>
      <div class="col-3 mb-2">
        <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/e/ec/Terrier_mixed-breed_dog.jpg/1024px-Terrier_mixed-breed_dog.jpg" class="img-thumbnail">
      </div>
      <div class="col-3 mb-2">
        <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/e/ec/Terrier_mixed-breed_dog.jpg/1024px-Terrier_mixed-breed_dog.jpg" class="img-thumbnail">
      </div>
      <div class="col-3 mb-2">
        <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/e/ec/Terrier_mixed-breed_dog.jpg/1024px-Terrier_mixed-breed_dog.jpg" class="img-thumbnail">
      </div>
      <div class="col-3 mb-2">
        <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/e/ec/Terrier_mixed-breed_dog.jpg/1024px-Terrier_mixed-breed_dog.jpg" class="img-thumbnail">
      </div>
      <div class="col-3 mb-2">
        <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/e/ec/Terrier_mixed-breed_dog.jpg/1024px-Terrier_mixed-breed_dog.jpg" class="img-thumbnail">
      </div>
      <div class="col-3 mb-2">
        <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/e/ec/Terrier_mixed-breed_dog.jpg/1024px-Terrier_mixed-breed_dog.jpg" class="img-thumbnail">
      </div>
      <div class="col-3 mb-2">
        <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/e/ec/Terrier_mixed-breed_dog.jpg/1024px-Terrier_mixed-breed_dog.jpg" class="img-thumbnail">
      </div>
      <div class="col-3 mb-2">
        <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/e/ec/Terrier_mixed-breed_dog.jpg/1024px-Terrier_mixed-breed_dog.jpg" class="img-thumbnail">
      </div>
      <div class="col-3 mb-2">
        <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/e/ec/Terrier_mixed-breed_dog.jpg/1024px-Terrier_mixed-breed_dog.jpg" class="img-thumbnail">
      </div>
      <div class="col-3 mb-2">
        <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/e/ec/Terrier_mixed-breed_dog.jpg/1024px-Terrier_mixed-breed_dog.jpg" class="img-thumbnail">
      </div>
    </div>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary w-100 btn-lg">Insert</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Or** a second scenario where the button is also inside the scroll:

```html
<!-- CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-TX8t27EcRE3e/ihU7zmQxVncDAy5uIKz4rEkgIXeMed4M0jlfIDPvg6uqKI2xXr2" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- jQuery and JS bundle w/ Popper.js -->
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ho+j7jyWK8fNQe+A12Hb8AhRq26LrZ/JpcUGGOn+Y7RsweNrtN/tE3MoK7ZeZDyx" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="card shadow m-3" style="width:500px; height: 280px">
  <div class="card-body h-100 overflow-auto">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-3 mb-2">
        <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/e/ec/Terrier_mixed-breed_dog.jpg/1024px-Terrier_mixed-breed_dog.jpg" class="img-thumbnail">
      </div>
      <div class="col-3 mb-2">
        <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/e/ec/Terrier_mixed-breed_dog.jpg/1024px-Terrier_mixed-breed_dog.jpg" class="img-thumbnail">
      </div>
      <div class="col-3 mb-2">
        <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/e/ec/Terrier_mixed-breed_dog.jpg/1024px-Terrier_mixed-breed_dog.jpg" class="img-thumbnail">
      </div>
      <div class="col-3 mb-2">
        <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/e/ec/Terrier_mixed-breed_dog.jpg/1024px-Terrier_mixed-breed_dog.jpg" class="img-thumbnail">
      </div>
      <div class="col-3 mb-2">
        <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/e/ec/Terrier_mixed-breed_dog.jpg/1024px-Terrier_mixed-breed_dog.jpg" class="img-thumbnail">
      </div>
      <div class="col-3 mb-2">
        <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/e/ec/Terrier_mixed-breed_dog.jpg/1024px-Terrier_mixed-breed_dog.jpg" class="img-thumbnail">
      </div>
      <div class="col-3 mb-2">
        <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/e/ec/Terrier_mixed-breed_dog.jpg/1024px-Terrier_mixed-breed_dog.jpg" class="img-thumbnail">
      </div>
      <div class="col-3 mb-2">
        <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/e/ec/Terrier_mixed-breed_dog.jpg/1024px-Terrier_mixed-breed_dog.jpg" class="img-thumbnail">
      </div>
      <div class="col-3 mb-2">
        <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/e/ec/Terrier_mixed-breed_dog.jpg/1024px-Terrier_mixed-breed_dog.jpg" class="img-thumbnail">
      </div>
      <div class="col-3 mb-2">
        <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/e/ec/Terrier_mixed-breed_dog.jpg/1024px-Terrier_mixed-breed_dog.jpg" class="img-thumbnail">
      </div>
      <div class="col-3 mb-2">
        <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/e/ec/Terrier_mixed-breed_dog.jpg/1024px-Terrier_mixed-breed_dog.jpg" class="img-thumbnail">
      </div>
    </div>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary w-100 btn-lg">Insert</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: In an attempt to simplify, I omitted a detail wherein the card body actually contains multiple panes selected with navs. So if I put the button in the footer of the card, it appears in all panes, but I only want it to appear in *one* of the panes. Is there a way to do this without moving the button out to the card footer?

Comment: I've added a new snippet. You can look at it.