# Div extending far outside modal, want it to stay inside and scroll

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog

I have a modal with fixed size. It contains multiple panes selectable with nav buttons. On one of the panes I have a div containing a grid of thumbnail images and a button at the bottom. Currently the images and the button extend far past the bottom of the modal window. I would like the button to remain at the bottom of the pane, and the remaining height of the pane be occupied with the thumbnail `div.row`, wherein if the image content does not fit inside of the `div.row`, the content scrolls.

My attempt at this was to make the pane `flex-column`, and make the `div.row` `overflow-auto`, but it has no effect it seems.

HTML

```
<div class="modal modal-base">
  <div class="modal-overlay"></div>
  <div class="modal-window">
    <div class="close">&times;</div>
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="nav-wrapper">
        <ul class="nav nav-pills flex-row" role="tablist">
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link mb-3 active" href="#" role="tab">Image List</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link mb-3" href="#" role="tab">Upload</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div class="card shadow mb-0">
        <div class="card-body">
          <div class="tab-content">
            <div class="tab-pane fade show active d-flex flex-column" role="tabpanel">
              <div class="row overflow-auto">
                <div class="col-6 mb-2">
                  <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/e/ec/Terrier_mixed-breed_dog.jpg/1024px-Terrier_mixed-breed_dog.jpg" class="img-thumbnail">
                </div>
                <div class="col-6 mb-2">
                  <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/e/ec/Terrier_mixed-breed_dog.jpg/1024px-Terrier_mixed-breed_dog.jpg" class="img-thumbnail">
                </div>
                <div class="col-6 mb-2">
                  <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/e/ec/Terrier_mixed-breed_dog.jpg/1024px-Terrier_mixed-breed_dog.jpg" class="img-thumbnail">
                </div>
              </div>
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary w-100 btn-lg">Insert</button>
            </div>
            <div class="tab-pane fade" role="tabpanel">
              <div class="upload-widget"></div>
              <div class="text-center mt-2">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Upload</button>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS (scss)

```
.modal {
  &.modal-base {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
  }

  &-overlay {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 2000;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  }

  &-window {
    background: #fff;
    border-radius: 4px;
    margin: auto;
    position: relative;
    width: 400px;
    height: 300px;
    z-index: 2001;

    .close {
      position: absolute;
      right: 2px;
      top: 2px;
      color: gray;
      font-size: 25px;
      z-index: 2002;
    }
  }

  &-content {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    padding: 20px;
  }
}
```

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/ChiliTomatoNoodle/pen/xxOmMvr?editors=1100)

Using Bootstrap 4 CSS framework. The JS code for the pane switching has been omitted since it is superfluous. I would like a solution that does not require me to fix the height of the `div` containing the images.

Note: this is a continuation of the question asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64807476/prevent-content-from-extending-outside-of-div-and-make-it-scroll). In that question I had simplified my setup to make everyone's life easier, and was able to get a working solution for that simplified setup, but it does not seem to work when translated over the actual setup I have, hence this question.

Thank you for looking at my question!

Comment: Is it what are you looking for?
https://codepen.io/sergeysolin/pen/KKMbjYm?editors=1100

Comment: @inser Yeah, pretty much! Though I would prefer using overflow-auto instead of augmenting the .shadow class, you hit the nail on the head there. If you could explain a bit on why it's necessary on both the div.row and div.shadow, I'd be much obliged (and also make sure you submit as an answer so I can accept+upvote).

Comment: @inser Oh wait nevermind, I see that you put the button in the card footer. Doing this means it will be visible on all panes, but I only want the button present on *one* of the panes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this issue (with help from an online friend) over the course of a few hours, allow me to share the insight gained.

Essentially, flex is the way to go here. We need flex in the pane to keep the button on the bottom while the images take up the remaining space with scrolling overflow. We should also make enclosing divs have a height of 100% (.tab-content, .card-body).

When we get to the .card itself is where things get tricky. We want it to fill the parent, but applying h-100 here is not acceptable since it has a sibling, its height shouldn't be 100% of the parent content area, but rather 100% - height of the .nav-wrapper. It's close to what we want, but not quite.

Seems like we need another flex here to allow the .card to grow just into the remaining space, but if you set the flex here, it is not respected and the card extends way outside of the modal. The secret sauce is that by default, the .card with .d-flex is getting min-height:auto, and what this means is that it will not shrink smaller than the size of its content. Setting min-height:0 on the div.card solves the problem. Since I do not see any Bootstrap utility to do this, I've added one myself globally for this purpose to use in the future as well.

```
.d-flex > .flex-shrink-content {
  min-height: 0;
}
```

The full code / demo can be found here for those interested:
[Codepen](https://codepen.io/ChiliTomatoNoodle/pen/xxOMLMv)

```
<div class="modal modal-base">
  <div class="modal-overlay"></div>
  <div class="modal-window">
    <div class="close">&times;</div>
    <div class="modal-content d-flex flex-column">
      <div class="nav-wrapper flex-grow-1">
        <ul class="nav nav-pills flex-row" role="tablist">
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link mb-3 active" href="#" role="tab">Image List</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link mb-3" href="#" role="tab">Upload</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div class="card flex-shrink-content shadow">
        <div class="card-body h-100">
          <div class="tab-content h-100">
            <div class="tab-pane fade show active d-flex flex-column h-100" role="tabpanel">
              <div class="row flex-grow-1 overflow-auto">
                <div class="col-6 mb-2">
                  <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/e/ec/Terrier_mixed-breed_dog.jpg/1024px-Terrier_mixed-breed_dog.jpg" class="img-thumbnail">
                </div>
                <div class="col-6 mb-2">
                  <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/e/ec/Terrier_mixed-breed_dog.jpg/1024px-Terrier_mixed-breed_dog.jpg" class="img-thumbnail">
                </div>
                <div class="col-6 mb-2">
                  <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/e/ec/Terrier_mixed-breed_dog.jpg/1024px-Terrier_mixed-breed_dog.jpg" class="img-thumbnail">
                </div>
              </div>
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary w-100 btn-lg mt-2">Insert</button>
            </div>
            <div class="tab-pane fade h-100" role="tabpanel">
              <div class="upload-widget"></div>
              <div class="text-center mt-2">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Upload</button>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

```
.modal {
  &.modal-base {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
  }

  &-overlay {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 2000;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  }

  &-window {
    background: #fff;
    border-radius: 4px;
    margin: auto;
    position: relative;
    width: 400px;
    height: 300px;
    z-index: 2001;

    .close {
      position: absolute;
      right: 2px;
      top: 2px;
      color: gray;
      font-size: 25px;
      z-index: 2002;
    }

  }

  &-content {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    padding: 20px;
  }
  
}

.d-flex > .flex-shrink-content {
  min-height: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should include an `overflow:auto;` or do the css code at your containing element

```
containing element {
    content:"";
    display:table;
    clear:both;
}
```

Comment: The containing element is already `overflow: auto`: `<div class="row overflow-auto">`

Answer (score 0):

Just provide your div containing the card class with appropriate overflow property like this:

`<div class="card shadow mb-0" style="overflow-x: hidden; overflow-y: scroll;">`

Comment: If we do as you suggest, the entire content of the card will scroll, including the button. I require the button to remain at the bottom of its pane, and only the image content in that pane to scroll.